# Nuxt remove leading "/" in link - Error generating route "/https://duckduckgo.com": This page could not be found

Tags: nuxt.js

My a href links in nuxt are generating with a leading '/' when I run

```
$ npm run build && npm run generate
```

Getting:

"/https://duckduckgo.com" wanting "https://duckduckgo.com"

^

The data structure looks like this, and what's happening is our custom nuxt app which is only a few highly designed custom pages is pointing across to an external CMS with lots of pages the needs me to reference full uri's.

```
export default {
  name: "CustomHeader",
  data() {
    return {
      isNotification: true,
      isOpen: false,
      isMobile: false,
      navitems: {
        about: {
          title: "about",
          subnav: [
            {
              title: "History",
              link: "https://example.com/p/history",
            },
            {
              title: "FAQ",
              link: "https://example.com/p/faq",
            },
          ],
        },
        resources: {
          title: "resources",
          subnav: [
            {
              title: "Media",
              link: "https://example.com/p/manifestos",
            },
            {
              title: "Magazine",
              link: "https://example.com/p/magazine",
            }
          ],
        },
      };
    }  
  }
};
```

How do I stop this leading '/' from generating.

I'm iterating a list of uri's into the href field so it's not as simple as just making a standard a href link.

```
    <div class="space-y-30px" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
      <a :href="item.link" @click="isOpen === false">{{
        item.title
      }}</a>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your 'items' data object look like? 
You could use str.slice() if you just needed to modify a string.

Comment: I tried to hack in a str.slice() and all it did is cut my url but kept the leading slash '/'.. this is what it returned "/ttps://duckduckgo.com".